# Parametrizar contagem de viagens em uma rotina select VBA

Tags: microsoft-access, vba

Gostaria de obter a seguinte `select`, para tanto vou fornecer o exemplo abaixo, lembrando que utilizo o VBA do Access 2007.

**Objetivo**: Contar as viagens efetuadas pelos veículos da frota por Linha / Sentido. Levando em consideração os seguintes parâmetros:

- 1º O veiculo precisa estar na mesma linha e sentido - com usuários embarcando sistematicamente com alguns intervalos de minutos, ou segundos.
- 2º Estando na mesma linha e sentido e constatar que um usuário embarcou com uma diferença de 30 minutos em relação ao anterior, considerar uma nova viagem adotando-se os mesmos parametros descritos no item 1º.
- 3º Adotar mesmos procedimentos descritos nos itens 1º e 2º se a qualquer momento observar mudança de linha e sentido.

Exemplo prático:

```
veiculo sentido linha       data/hora 
91        Ida     9b  31.03.2014 06:00:25
91        Ida     9b  31.03.2014 06:01:32
91        Ida     9b  31.03.2014 06:02:42
91        Ida     9b  31.03.2014 06:40:45
91        Ida     9b  31.03.2014 06:41:55
91        Volta   9b  31:03.2014 06:45:55
91        Ida     9b  31.03.2014 07:01:55
91        Ida    33A  31.03.2014 07:30:00
91        Ida    33A  31.03.2014 07:30:55
```

Resultado esperado para o exemplo acima, e de acordo com os parâmetros fornecidos, seria:

```
CONTAGEM DE VIAGENS FINAL PARA O VEICULO 91

VEICULO SENTIDO LINHA      INICIO                FIM                 VIAGEM
91        Ida     9b   31.03.2014 06:00:25    31.03.2014 06:02:42       1
91        Ida     9b   31.03.2014 06:40:45    31.03.2014 06:41:55       2
91        Volta   9b   31.03.2014 06:45:55    31.03.2014 06:45:55       3
91        Ida     9b   31.03.2014 07:01:55    31.03.2014 07:01:55       5
91        Ida    33A   31.03.2014 07:30:00    31.03.2014 07:30:55       6
```

Portanto:
O veiculo 91 realizou no dia 31.03.2014 6 viagens distribuídas conforme acima:
É claro que o exemplo acima é bem resumido, porque na realidade são milhares de usuários e diversos veículos...

Comment: você chegou a desenvolver alguma coisa do seu select?

Comment: É possível definir mais precisamente "com alguns intervalos de minutos" para tentar montar uma expressão no SQL? Você disse que 30 minutos não vale, mas e 15, 10 ou 5 minutos?

Comment: O Ideal é montar umas tabelas auxiliares pra te ajudar e simplificar o problema. Eu consego ver uma solução pra voce, gerando uma coluna adiciona por cada linha informando o tempo de diferença entre o registro atual e o registro anterior. Depois com esse campo voce gera o segund ocampo informando quando que o tempo é superior a 30 e informa um true ou false, se é corte. Por fim num ultimo select vc agrupa esses dados e exibe numa pivot.

Comment: Agradeço a atenção dos usuários Math - Osvaldo e Roger...

Comment: Ao Math informo que basicamente tudo que desenvolvo em access é via assitente, não sou muito bom em vba.....

Comment: Ao Osvaldo, informou que os 30 minutos é um parametro fixo de intervalo, porém nada me impediria no futuro de modifica-lo para mais ou para menos...veja geralmente um onibus circulando tem embarques regulares de usuários que geralmente não ultrapassam 30 minutos, portanto como um veiculo as vezes pode continuar no sentido ida indefinidamente durante o dia, resolvemos adotar este critério...OK.....

Comment: Ao Roger, informo que entendi perfeitamente, porém tenho dificuldades em escrever este racicíonio em VBA, Assim: podedia "se possivel" me auxiliar neste projeto ? ....

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode ser solucionado com 3 consultas/passos

Passo 1 explicado:

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP1 --Crio uma tabela temporária através da consulta
FROM (SELECT 
        *,  
        IIF( --Teste logico para verificar se é final de viagem
            DateDiff('s',T1.Data, 

                                    (
                                            SELECT 
                                            -- Aqui eu faço uma esperteza, se por acaso não existir data (null), trago a data da propria linha
                                            -- Desta forma quando for nulo, o datediff será igual a zero

                                            IIF(MIN(T2.Data) Is Null, T1.Data, MIN(T2.Data)) 
                                        FROM Plan1 T2  
                                        WHERE 
                                            T2.Cod_Veiculo = T1.Cod_Veiculo 
                                            AND T2.Cod_Linha = T1.Cod_Linha 
                                            AND T1.Direcao = T2.Direcao 
                                            AND T2.Data > T1.Data 
                                            AND DateDiff('s',T1.Data, T2.Data) <= 1800
                                    ) --Procuro pela menor data existente na tabela para o mesmo veículo, direcao e linha onde a 
                                      -- data é maior que a atual e a diferenca em segundos seja menor que 1800 (30 min)


            -- Se nao encontrar nenhuma data posterior (Retornar nulo e Datediff = 0), o campo retorna verdadeiro
            ) = 0, True, False 
        ) As FimDaViagem
        ,  

        --Teste logico para verificar se é início de viagem
        IIF(

            DateDiff('s',T1.Data, 
                                    (
                                        SELECT 

                                            -- Aqui eu faço uma esperteza, se por acaso não existir data (null), trago a data da propria linha
                                            -- Desta forma quando for nulo, o datediff será igual a zero

                                            IIF(MAX(T2.Data) Is Null, T1.Data, MAX(T2.Data)) 
                                        FROM Plan1 T2  
                                        WHERE 
                                            T2.Cod_Veiculo = T1.Cod_Veiculo 
                                            AND T2.Cod_Linha = T1.Cod_Linha 
                                            AND T1.Direcao = T2.Direcao 
                                            AND T2.Data < T1.Data 
                                            AND DateDiff('s',T2.Data, T1.Data) < 1800

                                            --Procuro pela maior data existente na tabela para o mesmo veículo, direcao e linha onde a 
                                            -- data é menor que a atual e diferenca em segundos desta data seja menor que 1800 (30 min)
                                    )
            ) = 0, True, False
        ) As InicioDaViagem
    FROM 
        Plan1 T1
)  AS TT1

-- Na tabela temporaria TEMP1 insiro apenas as pontas de inicio e fim de viagem identificadas
WHERE TT1.FimDaViagem = True OR TT1.InicioDaViagem = True

-- Ordenaçao padrao por veículo e data
ORDER BY TT1.Cod_Veiculo, TT1.Data;
```

Passo 2 - Explicado

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
        Count(*) -- Numero de Flags de FimDeViagens/InicioDeViagens que acontecerem a partir da data do registro atual
    FROM 
        TEMP1 T2 
    WHERE 
        (T2.FimDaViagem = IIF(T1.FimDaViagem,True,False))  -- Se for um registro de FimDeViagem, conto o numero de Fins de Viagem e vice-versa
        AND T2.Data <= T1.Data 
        AND T1.Cod_veiculo = T2.Cod_Veiculo

    -- Crio um vínculo em comum entre o registro de inicio e o registro de fim de viagem respectivamente baseado no veiculo e nas ocorrencias 
    -- a partir da data do registro atual

) AS Vinculo, * 
INTO TEMP2

FROM 
TEMP1
```

Passo 3 - Consulta Final

```
SELECT 
T1.Cod_Veiculo, 
DateValue(T1.Data) AS Data, 
T1.Direcao AS Sentido, 
T1.Cod_Linha, 
T1.Data AS Data_Inicio, 
T2.Data AS Data_Fim, 

(
    -- Soma o numero de registros de fim de viagem onde o veículo é igual ao veículo atual
    SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM 
        TEMP2 T3 
    WHERE 
        T3.FimDaViagem = True 
        AND T3.Cod_Veiculo = T1.Cod_Veiculo
) AS NrViagens
FROM 
TEMP2 AS T1, -- Trago duas vezes a tabela TEMP2 vinculando o mesmo registro de FIm com o de Inicio dela pelo numero do viculo + veículo
TEMP2 AS T2
WHERE 
T1.InicioDaViagem =  True -- Garanto que na T1 sao apenas os dados de inuicio de viagem
AND T2.FimDaViagem = True -- Garanto que na T2 sao apenas os dados de fim de viagem
AND T1.Vinculo = T2.Vinculo -- Vinculo entre T1 e T2
AND T1.Cod_Veiculo = T2.Cod_Veiculo -- Vinculo entre T1 e T2;
```